# How to Bind DataGrid in DataGrid.RowDetailTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am created a DataGrid with DataGrid in RowDataTemplete.I need to bind it in following ways

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="#FFDED6D6">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="#FF9C2626" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birthday" Binding="{Binding Birthday}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel Background="GhostWhite">
                    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="64" Margin="10" />
                    <Grid Margin="0,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item"  Binding="{Binding Path=Items.item}" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="#FF9C2626" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Binding="{Binding Path=Items.qty}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

The cs code is given below

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        users.Add(new User() { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23), ImageUrl = "http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/images/misc/john_doe.jpg", Items = new Items() { item="Thenga",qty="2"} });
                    users.Add(new User() { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17), Items = new Items() { item="Olakka",qty="5"}  });
                    users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2), Items = new Items() { item = "Punnaak", qty = "3" } });

                    dgUsers.ItemsSource = users;
    }
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public Items Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Items
    {
        public string item { get; set; }
        public string qty { get; set; }
    }

}
```

After Running above code; RowDetailsTemplate not binding with my data.I need your helps to Bind DataGrid with DataGrid as RowDetailsTemplate

Comment: If I understand what you want to do then your inner data grid items source should bind to `Items` property: `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` but that won't work as `Items` is not a list. I think you want a list there

Comment: Yes...I already do it with ItemsSource but data not bind on ListView

Comment: What `ListView`? There is not list view here. There `DataGrid` with inner `DataGrid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem you want to bind inner `DataGrid` to `Items` property. If that's the case then first problem here is you need to bind `ItemsSource` to `Items` property instead of whole `User` and then bind columns of inner `DataGrid` to properties of `Items`

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <!-- .... -->
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ...>
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item"  Binding="{Binding Path=item}" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="#FF9C2626" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Binding="{Binding Path=qty}" IsReadOnly="True" />
          </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
      <!-- .... -->
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Second problem is that `Users` is a single item, not a list. If you want to bind something to `ItemsSource` property it must be an `IEnumerable` so in your view model convert it to a list

```
public class User
{
    ....

    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}
```